# Save a new entity (play) only if there is not a clash of date and time

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am building a booking system in Python and SQLite.

I have a Staff.db and Play.db (one-to-many relationship).
The idea is the following: the only staff member of the theater can choose when to add a play by specifying its starting date and time. I saved the date/time in the Play.db as string 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'.
However, since the theater has only one room, the staff member can add the play only if its time 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM' does not clash with already existing plays.
Important information: each play lasts 1 hour only.

**My question:**
How can I create a python function or SQLite query to allow the staff member to add the new play only when it does not class with already existing plays?

I realized two things:

- I have to get the starting date of each play
- To this starting date, I have to add +1 hour so that I know if this 'period' is free

The issue is that I tried unsuccesfully some queries with SQL but I am not really sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (I would think):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
next_hour = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
next_hour = next_hour.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE "
         "play_start >= %s AND plan_start <= %s" % (now, next_hour))
# If the query value is larger than 0, you have a clash
```

Of course, this example uses `now()` as the lookup time. You would clearly substitute the actual time being searched, but I used `now()` as an example.